# JQuery closest() + find() tree traversal

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Given a structure like this:

```
<div class="portlet">
    <div class="portlet-config">
        <p>Some configuration</p>
    </div>
    <div class="portlet-header">Configurable portlet</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">This has a configuration window. Click on pencil icon to open.</div>
</div>
```

First, I append these DIVs to portlet-header (to display some buttons)

```
<div class="portlet-button-container">
    <div class="portlet-button portlet-btn-delete ui-icon ui-icon-close"></div>
    <div class="portlet-button portlet-btn-toggle ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick"></div>
    <div class="portlet-button portlet-btn-config ui-icon ui-icon-pencil"></div>
</div>
```

Then I apply a jquery-ui `dialog()` plugin to the `portlet-config` DIVs

```
$(".portlet-config").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: {
        effect: "fade",
        duration: 200
    },
    hide: {
        effect: "fade",
        duration: 500
    },
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        Ok: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

Then I add come click handlers

```
$(".portlet-btn-toggle").click(function () {
    var icon = $(this);
    icon.toggleClass("ui-icon-minusthick ui-icon-plusthick");
    icon.closest(".portlet").find(".portlet-content").toggle();
});

$(".portlet-btn-delete").click(function () {
    var icon = $(this);
    icon.closest(".portlet").hide();
});

$(".portlet-btn-config").click(function () {
    var icon = $(this);
    icon.closest(".portlet").find(".portlet-config").dialog("open");
});
```

It seems that the `portlet-config` DIV could not be found when the user clicks on the pencil.

More precisely it seems that:

```
$(this)                                             // OK, returns an object
$(this).closest(".portlet")                         // OK, returns an object
$(this).closest(".portlet").find(".portlet-config") // NOK, returns null
```

Here is a fiddle to reproduce the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/silenzioso/M6LmS/

Thanks in advance

Comment: `// NOK, returns null`, `find` doesn't return null.

Comment: since you are calling `$(".portlet-config").dialog()` the dom structure gets modified and the `portlet-config` is no longer a descendant of `portlet` element. that is why it is failing... if there is only one `portlet-config` then just call `$(".portlet-config").dialog("open");`

Comment: Unfortunately, there could be more than one structures like that, that's why I have to use that traversal to find that specific DIV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `$(".portlet-config").dialog` is doing a little more than you expect it to. If you look in the DOM, you can see that the div has been moved out of its original location and added to the end of the document. Presumably it does this for the overlayed dialog effect.

You could consider putting a unique ID on the dialog div so that you can find it again. Perhaps you could use a data attribute to store the associated dialog div ID in the button.

```
<div class="portlet">
    <div class="portlet-config" id="dialog1">
        <p>Some configuration</p>
    </div>
    <div class='portlet-button' data-config="dialog1"></div>
</div>

...

var id = $(this).data('config');
var config = $('#'+id);
```

Comment: That could be a solution, but I add buttons DIVs dynamically, hence I cannot add different data-config attribute

Comment: Can you generate a new ID from a counter and put it in the string?

Comment: Yes, I will try that way

Answer (score 0):

If You are dynamically creating new DOM elements in jQuery make sure You add event click on body or document or other element that is defined from the very first page display (I mean server response):

```
$('body').on('click', '.portlet-btn-config', function(e){

});
```